# FishEye selected image index or something

Tags: wpf, fisheye

I am quite new to WPF.I came accross this [wonderful project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Panels.aspx). I have planed to use it. I have used it to show the fish eye effect how ever I want that if it is possible to see which image is selected and if it gets clicked i get to know which index or something so that i can do some logic.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article describes the creation of a custom panel. A panel in WPF describes layout but does not support selection. In order to support selection you need to use a control such as ListBox. Fortunately the ListBox allows you to specify which panel to use to fost your content:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <!-- the custom fish eye panel -->
      <FishEyePanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Whether this works or not depends on the implementation of the fish-eye panel. However, this is the right direction to move in!